# MySql PDO Prepared Select Statement - Counting Results within Classes via PHP count()

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, count

I have quite an issue I can not seem to solve. I am trying to get a row count from a select statement.

I should start by saying I have tried most all methods resulting from google searches on this issue.

I am using the result set so I would prefer not to make a second query.

The query uses a prepared select statement which seems to be a main issue if I understand it correctly.

I decided to try a simple approach using PHP's native `count()` function. Which lead me here because I finally reached the end of the rope on this.

On to the details...within a class of mine, I make the query like this.

```
    // Create database connection
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    // Set and execute database query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `service_orders` WHERE `agency_id` = :agency_id $filter ORDER BY $sort $order $per_page"; 
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($query_array);

    // If results
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {                               
            $results = $query->fetchAll();              
            self::$order_count = "Count: " . count($results);
            return $results;
    }

    // Default, return false
    return false;
```

**Findings**

1. If I perform `count($results)` like I did above, I get the total rows in the database (Let's say 50).
2. If I `print_r($results)`, it shows the array with the proper number of entries (Let's say 10) that of course differs from the total rows in the database.

How can these two differ? It's as if the `count($results)` is misreading the result array.

**More Findings**

Within my actual php page, I call the class to retrieve the data like this.

```
$results = OrderModel::getServiceOrders();
echo count($results);
```

Strangely enough, if I then perform `count($results)` it gives me the correct reading of the result array (which in my example here would be 10).

I am perplexed by this as the count function is being performed on the exact same array. The only difference is one is called on the array within the class, and the other is called on the array returned from the class.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this or why there is the discrepancy when using `count()` in this instance?

Thank you all in advance!
James

**Additional Info**

This is another mind numbing scenario. If I return the count along with the actual results, I can access it on the page with the correct value (10 rows). Yet, if I set it into a session variable, and access it that way, the count is the whole data set (50 rows). How is it even possible these two values are not the same?!

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();              
Session::set("order_count", $total[0]); // Yields 50 (incorrect)
return [
    "results"=> $results,
    "count"=> $total[0], // Yields 10 (correct)
];
```

Comment: What is in `$query->rowCount()`? Isn't what you need?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That gives the row count of the whole table.

Comment: just debug your code. there is obviously no generic answer for such a question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Man, that's what I have been doing. It's driving me nuts. If I return the count along with the results, I can access the count successfully. But if I add the count into a session variable, when I access that, it shows the count of the full result set. It make zero sense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Check my addition at the bottom. You can take away all the rest of my issues and I still can not get around how that is even possible?

Comment: The code submitted does not seem to contain all relevant information. ie From what method are you returning.

Comment: @davidstrachan The class/method is `OrderModel::getServiceOrders();` and the query is within that method.

Comment: Are you using any framework? Sometimes another class is transforming the resultset.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Yeah, I am using a small MVC. I have followed the trail through the framework and nothing directly modifies the query unless another method is specifically called on the query.

Comment: Show `getServiceOrders()` code.